# How can I avoid the extra padding above my text?

Tags: html, css

There is some padding inside my text box that I'd like to eliminate. Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>I am testing text. Hello WORLD.</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

The results in some padding above the text inside the box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFOt5.png

As you can see, right above the top of the text, there are a few pixels of padding that I can't seem to be able to get rid of. Is there anything I can do to eliminate that padding (preferable without a hardcoded adjustment value)?

The code for this question is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TL7VC/

Comment: Is this what you're referring to...? http://jsfiddle.net/qQEPQ/ Otherwise, I don't see any padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no padding. The initial value of the `padding` property is 0, and there is no reason why `padding` for `div` would be nonzero, unless you set it so.

When text is set solid, i.e. `line-height: 1`, the line height equals the height of the font, which is the same as the size of the font. The height of most characters is smaller than the height of the font. Roughly speaking, the height of the font accommodates *all* characters, including those with ascenders and descenders and diacritic marks above and below, like Å, Ê, and j. (In a detailed look, you may see that some characters may even extend a bit above the height of the font, depending on the font.)

You can try to tweak this by setting `line-height` to a value smaller than 1, say 0.8. Then you might see e.g. “H” as toucjing the top of the colored area. But this will depend on the font, as it is the font designer’s decision how the places characters with respect to the font size.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a padding, but  height of font. Put some big character like this

```
↑ ░ ↓
```

to the row to see there is no padding

Answer (score 0):

add `margin:0px` and `padding:0px;`  to your body. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TL7VC/4/)